# AngularJS changing dynamic $http.get

Tags: angularjs, json, http

I have recently learned AngularJS. I started a small project. I was able to extract data from a json file. My current task is to be able to extract data from multiple json files. How can I do this?

I made my first json file this way:

```
$http.get("personel.json")
            .then(function(gelen) {
                $scope.personeller = gelen.data;
            });
```

I have 9 more json files that I need to take, but I want to see the data of the file I'm calling

```
$http.get("1.json")
            .then(function(veri1) {
                $scope.x1 = veri1.data;
            });
```

the other files are named "1.json, 2.json, 3.json ....... 9.json"

---

**How can I change the location of the 1.json in the top code block?I am sorry for my English.The first time I am writing to a foreign forum. Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.getdetail = function(detail) {
    $scope.result = detail;

    $http.get($scope.result.id + ".json")
        .then(function(veri1) {
            $scope.x1 = veri1.data;
        });
}
```

**I solved my problem this way thanks.**

Answer (score -2):

You can wrap the $http call in a function and pass in the filename you wish to retrieve like this:

**Edit** I modifed the code here adding a promise to handle issues that could arise from asynchronous requests

```
$scope.getFile = async function(fileName){
    return new Promise((res, err) => {
        $http.get(fileName).then(function(result){
             res(result.data);
        })
    })
}

$scope.file1 = $scope.getFile("1.json");
$scope.file2 = $scope.getFile("2.json");
$scope.file3 = $scope.getFile("3.json");
$scope.file4 = $scope.getFile("4.json");
$scope.file5 = $scope.getFile("5.json");
$scope.file6 = $scope.getFile("6.json");
$scope.file7 = $scope.getFile("7.json");
$scope.file8 = $scope.getFile("8.json");
$scope.file9 = $scope.getFile("9.json");
```

If the files are sequential and numeric you could also use this to pull all the data from the file into a single array using a for loop.

```
$scope.returnedFiles = [];
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    $scope.getFile(i + ".json").then(fileData => {
        $scope.returnedFiles.push(fileData);
    });

}
```

Comment: `$http.get` is an asynchronous call, when you write `$scope.returnedFiles.push(file);` you may push empty/null object.

Your code may not work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @carmelolg I modified my code to account for this issue.

Comment: you're welcome, now you need only to manage the promise that you return before.

Comment: The ES6 promises returned by `async` are not integrated with the AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. The $http service already returns an AngularJS promise. There is no need to manufacture a new one with `new Promise`. The manufactured promise hangs if the $http service returns a rejected promise.